# Grouping objects in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder, ellipse

So I'm currently making a JavaFX GUI (with SceneBuilder) for a Connect4 game, and I was wondering if there's a way to 'group' objects together so that I can perform an action on all of them together?

Examples of what I mean:

- I have 7 buttons for the columns (colButton1-7) and I want to disable all of them at once.
- I use Ellipses for counters (counter1-40) and would like to change the color of all of them to white.

I searched around but couldn't find anything. I know how to do both for an individual object, but can't think of a way to easily apply the changes to all of them at the same time. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no grouping mechanism to perform a single action on all of the members of the same group. On the contrary, you can have a single group/container to hold all your controls and apply the same action to each of its member.

For example, lets say I have a `VBox` containing `Buttons` and I want to *disable* them all.

```
for(Node node:vBox.getChildren()) {
    node.setDisable(true);
}
```

or, to set Styling

```
for(Node node:vBox.getChildren()) {
    node.setStyle("-fx-something");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I didn't know HBox and VBox existed, they are perfect. (One small pointer: the JavaFX code is `.setDisable(true);` rather than disabled)

Comment: You have many layout containers in JavaFX, you can read about them in [Working with Layouts in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html)

Comment: If you call setDisable(...) on a Parent node, the disabled state will propagate to all it's child nodes.

Comment: @James_D Does it apply for just `setDisable(..)` or are there other properties which behave in the same way?

Comment: For styled properties, you just need to set up the appropriate style sheet. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For disabling, if you disable a node, then all it's child nodes will have `disabled` set to true. So you can do:

```
VBox buttonHolder = new VBox();
Button button = new Button(...);
buttonHolder.getChildren().add(button);
// repeat as necessary...

buttonHolder.setDisable(true); // all buttons in the VBox will now be disbaled
```

For styled properties, such as the `fill` of a shape, you should use an external style sheet. If you change the style class of the parent, then with an appropriate external style sheet you can change the style of all the children in one shot.

E.g.

```
Pane counterPane = new Pane();
for (int i=0; i<numCounters; i++) {
    Ellipse counter = new Ellipse(...);
    counter.getStyleClass().add("counter");
    counterPane.getChildren().add(counter);
}

// ...

counterPane.getStyleClass().add("counter-pane"); // all counters white

// change to red:
counterPane.getStyleClass().remove("counter-pane");
counterPane.getStyleClass().add("warning");
```

External style sheet:

```
.counter-pane > .counter {
    -fx-fill: white ;
}

.warning > .counter {
    -fx-fill : red ;
}
```